# Deep Embedded Clustering - R Packages?

Tags: deep-learning, clustering

I would like to use Unsupervised Deep Learning approaches to cluster analyze of matrix of roughly 200 objects and 400 binary attributes.

Are you able to point me to any R packages that can do this?

I've been looking into TensorFlow/Keras but this combination appears to use supervised approaches (as far as I can tell with my limited experience).